# Problem running pointcloud_to_laserscan launch file

Tags: ros, sonar, roslaunch, nodelet, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to use the pointcloud_to_laserscan stack with data we have collected from a sonar scan which has been converted in to pointcloud2 data. I'm a little confused at how nodelet's and also pointcloud_to_laserscan's work. I found (and attempted to replicate for this application) the turtlebot launch files for use with Kinect (https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/ee8b48e42178/turtlebot_bringup/kinect.launch) however it's still a little unclear.

The below launch file runs without error, however no laserScan msg is output.

```
<launch>
    <!--    DISPLAY NAME    NODE NAME       RUN NAME        ARGUMENTS       -->
    <node name="Scanner"    pkg="sonar"     type="sonar"    />
    <node name="Injector"   pkg="sonarInjector"     type="sonarInjector"    />
    <node name="Pointcloud" pkg="sonarPointCloud"   type="sonarPointCloud"  />

    <!-- fake laser -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="sonarToLaser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan sonarPointCloud">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/base_sonar2"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="sonarPC"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="sonarLaserz"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

Any advice on which direction to go in next and what might be wrong.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37312/problem-running-pointcloud_to_laserscan-launch-file/) by [alexsleat](https://answers.ros.org/users/775/alexsleat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to get this working as a nodelet, by just adding a nodelet manager (as below).

I'm still working on getting the sonar data correctly in to it, if I'm successful I will make sure to submit the code.

```
<launch>

    <!--    DISPLAY NAME    NODE NAME   RUN NAME    ARGUMENTS   -->
    <!-- <node name="Scanner"   pkg="sonar" type="sonar"    /> -->
    <!-- <node name="Injector"  pkg="sonarInjector" type="sonarInjector"    /> -->
    <!-- <node name="Pointcloud"    pkg="sonarPointCloud"   type="sonarPointCloud"  /> -->

    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="sonarManager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>

<!-- fake laser -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="sonarToLaser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan sonarManager">
        <param name="output_frame_id" value="/base_sonar"/>
        <remap from="cloud" to="sonarPC"/>
        <remap from="scan" to="sonarLaser"/>
    </node>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [alexsleat](https://answers.ros.org/users/775/alexsleat/) with karma: 41 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A_Saeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/30290/a_saeed/) on 2017-05-07**:
Hi alex, my work is similar to yours, but I'm directly publishing pointcloud from sonar sensor using range finder, when I use your launch file at start the things work fine but as soon as I subscribe sonarLaser topic the process dies and previous subscription also terminates. Can you guide me please

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-07-17**:
FYI, I found that this code didn't work for me as-is. I got a bunch of errors about "CloudToScan" not being a nodelet package.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried running [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) as a node?

From what I understand, [nodelets](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet) require a nodelet manager to run. The turtlebot uses the openni_manager. Nodelets are used to process the same pointcloud through different algorithms (throttling, fake laser, narrow laser).

In your case, since you just need the fake laserscan, you probably can just run the pointcloud_to_laserscan as a node.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexsleat](https://answers.ros.org/users/775/alexsleat/) on 2012-06-26**:
I have attempted to run as a node, however also having some problems with that. I replaced lines 32-37 with 39 as here (https://gist.github.com/3003036) however this returns an "undefined reference to `main'". I'm assuming this will require more code modification?

Also, thanks for the help!